# A term for reaching the height that an airplane is going to keep at during most of the flight

Tags: phrase-request

What's the right expression in English to describe an airplanes' reaching the height that it is going to keep at during most of the flight?

For example:

> -- Excuse me, stewardess, can I have some Champagne?
>
> -- Oh, certainly! Except you need to wait a bit till we ___________________.

1) till we get the height?

2) till we finish taking off?

3) till we get to the right altitude?

or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This term is commonly referred to as *cruising altitude*:

> : the height in the sky at which an airplane stays for most of a flight
>   // The pilot announced that we'd reached *cruising altitude*.
>   // a *cruising altitude* of 40,000 feet

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cruising%20altitude))

So your example would become:

> Except you need to wait a bit till we *reach cruising altitude*.